# Using typedef with a template class

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic, stack, typedef

I have written this code, but it doesn't work!

It is the implementation of a node for a dynamic stack in C++:

```
template <class E>

class Record{

public:

    E elem;

    Record<E> *prec;
};


typedef Record<E> *P; <- error!
```

I can't solve it, any solution?
Thanks

Comment: You mean you get a compiler error? What is the error?

Comment: You need to replace `E` with an actual type. For example `typedef Record<int>* P;`

Comment: @juanchopanza.... why didn't you write that in the answer part?

Comment: @Michael I wasn't 100% sure of what OP actually wants to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typedef Record<E> *P; <- error!
```

You can't do a "template typedef" like this in C++03. You need to replace `E` with a concrete type.

In C++11, you can use a `using` alias, like so:

```
template <typename E>
using P = Record<E>*;

P<int> p;
P<float> q;
```

Comment: +1 because of the simple, thorough example, very well phrased!

Comment: +1 but note that the VC++ compiler still does not support template aliases, afaik.